# Slow jquery animate when clicked on id or a class

Tags: jquery, class, click, jquery-animate

for eg : I have a menu : Point A `<a id="pointA"></a>` and there is a Point B`<div id="pointB">` somewhere in the body. what I wanna do is when I click on point A it should scroll to Point B but slowly.

how can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [scrollto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Answer (score 1):

for scrolling to your point B when point A is clicked try something like that:

```
$("#pointA").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#pointB").offset().top
    }, 1500); //This value will define the speed/ duration of your animation
});
```

Comment: should I be loading jquery.1.11.1.js on header for this?

Comment: @PradeepGurung all versions of jQuery above 1.10 should work. Which one you chose depends on your other code and the browser-support. But Version 1.11 should be a good choice here

Comment: Thank you. It didn't worked but when I placed the code inside head, it worked. have you any idea about this issue?? before I wrote the script right above body end.

Comment: Have you tried to wrap an `$(document).ready()`-function around your code ? You should always do that

Comment: yes I did 
`<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
   {
   $(".pointA").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(".pointB").offset().top
  }, 2500);
  });
      });
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can write below code for scroll to div pointB 

<script>
$(function(){
$("#pointA").bind("click",function(event) {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#pointB").offset().top},
    1000); 
});});
</script>
```